# If I replace an old app with a new app with the same bundle ID and keychain values. Can the new app access the previously stored data?

Tags: android, keychain

If I download **App B** (React Native App) which has the same bundle ID and keychain values as **App A**. Can I access the locally stored SQLITE database of App A using App B? Can I migrate the local database from app A to App b?

Is it possible to have both App A and App B installed at the same time, or would the installation of App B overwrite App A?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

B will overwrite App A, and you can access the data you stored A

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't install 2 apps with the same bundle ID on the
   same device.
2. If you have installed App A with SQLite DB and you can overwrite App B with the same bundle ID, you can access DB of app A.

Let me know, If you have still any query...